# Mean by groups by multiple columns in r

Tags: r, row, multiple-columns, mean, group

I have the next dataframe

```
obs1   obs2   obs3   zone
1       0      1     Rural
1       1      1     Rural
0       1      1     Urban
1       0      0     Urban
0       1      0     Rural
```

I am trying to get something like this

```
Mean Rural    0.6666
Mean Urban    0.5
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an {dplyr} approach:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(zone) %>% 
  summarise(values = mean(c_across(obs1:obs3)))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   zone  values
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 Rural  0.667
#> 2 Urban  0.5


# data
dat <- tibble(obs1 = c(1,1,0,1,0),
       obs2 = c(0,1,1,0,1),
       obs3 = c(1,1,1,0,0),
       zone = c("Rural", "Rural", "Urban", "Urban", "Rural"))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
aggregate(values ~ zone, cbind(stack(df[-4]), df[4]), mean)

   zone    values
1 Rural 0.6666667
2 Urban 0.5000000
```

Or (assuming no missing values):

```
tapply(rowMeans(df[-4]), df[4], mean)

    Rural     Urban 
0.6666667 0.5000000
```